# Can we create a table using the output from a PIVOT statement in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, pivot

I have a table and using PIVOT statement over it returns the output I was looking for, now I need to store the same into a table for further calculations.

When I do something like this:

```
    create table new_table as 
(
select * from mytable
unpivot(period for months in 
(
"October 2019",
"November 2019",
"December 2019",
"January 2020",
"February 2020",
"March 2020" ))
pivot(
avg(period) 
for PROD_SKU in ('ABC123','DEF456')
)
order by 1);
```

it throws "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" error.

My pivot query works fine though!

Comment: please edit the question and show the complete create statement

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you don't need the brackets after `AS` and before `;`.

If you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  PROD_SKU,
  "October 2019",
  "November 2019",
  "December 2019",
  "January 2020",
  "February 2020",
  "March 2020"
) AS
SELECT 'ABC123', 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEF456', 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
create table new_table as 
select *
from   mytable
unpivot
(
  period
  for months in (
    "October 2019",
    "November 2019",
    "December 2019",
    "January 2020",
    "February 2020",
    "March 2020"
  )
)
pivot
(
  avg(period) 
  for PROD_SKU in ('ABC123','DEF456')
)
order by 1;
```

Then the `new_table` contains:

```sql
SELECT * FROM new_table;
```

> | MONTHS | 'ABC123' | 'DEF456' |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | December 2019 | 12 | 22 |
> | February 2020 | 14 | 24 |
> | January 2020 | 13 | 23 |
> | March 2020 | 15 | 25 |
> | November 2019 | 11 | 21 |
> | October 2019 | 10 | 20 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d9a1008e037aa0fd22e94bac7467f454)*